# How can I add Twitter and Facebook social media buttons to my web site?

Tags: html, twitter, web, facebook-like, social-networking

I want to add Twitter and Facebook social media buttons to my HTML5 app / web site. Does anybody have any "drop-in" code for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For facebook, see what button do you want to add, and use facebook's wizard for generation your custom code:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

and this one for twitter:

https://dev.twitter.com/

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded button images as jpegs and added a link to the image (using Kompozer software). Once they were added I also added target="_blank" before the link address to make sure a new tab is opened rather than redirecting the web user to someone else's site :)

```
target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/username
```

Answer (score 1):

Find suitable icons for yourself off line and add links to your facebook/twitter/linked in etc pages.

That way you have control over the design.

Answer (score 1):

just add icon of facebook, twitter or what you want and hyperlink the URL of this web where you want to redirect your audience.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your html page, right after the body and before header:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

(If you're using the Razor view engine in ASP.NET, add the above script to the _SiteLayout.cshtml file if you want the buttons on multiple pages).

Then add this at the spot where you want the button[s] to appear:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.awardwinnersonly.com" data-text="Czech out the books, movies, and music that won major awards" data-via="BClayShannon">Tweet</a>
    <script>!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.awardwinnersonly.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui">
</div>
```

Replace "http://www.awardwinnersonly.com" with your web site's URL, the Twitter "data-text" value with what you want a tweet to say by default, and the Twitter "data-via" (not to be confused with Pancho Villa) value with your Twitter handle.

Also, add this, if you want a Facebook comments button (from Tito Tito's accepted answer):

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.awardwinnersonly.com" data-colorscheme="The color scheme used in the plugin" data-numposts="5" data-width="450"></div>
```